# Is the comma in Perl associative in all contexts?

Tags: perl, expression, operator-precedence, associativity

Suppose `E`, `F`, and `G` are expressions that don't involve operators of higher precedence than the comma. Are the expressions `((E, F), G)` and `(E, (F, G))` equivalent in scalar, list, and/or void  contexts? More precisely, can you always replace `((E, F), G)` with `(E, (F, G))` and vice-versa without affecting program execution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Context does not affect how code is parsed.

The comma/list operator is guaranteed to evaluate each operand from left to right (regardless of context).

From that and a couple more pieces of information, we can prove that `E, F, G`, `( E, F ), G` and `E, ( F, G )` are equivalent.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

Since you specifically mentioned context, we'll look at that in more detail.

For void, list or indeterminate<sup>[2]</sup> context *c*, we get the same context *c* for each item in all cases.

```
   c               c                 c
-------       -----------       -----------
c  c  c          c      c       c     c
-  -  -       --------  -       -  --------
                c  c                 c  c
                -  -                 -  -
E, F, G       ( E, F ), G       E, ( F, G )
```

For scalar context (*s*), we get void context (*v*) for all but the last item in all cases.

```
   s               s                 s
-------       -----------       -----------
v  v  s          v      s       v     s
-  -  -       --------  -       -  --------
                v  v                 v  s
                -  -                 -  -
E, F, G       ( E, F ), G       E, ( F, G )
```

---

1. I'd love to be able to say they compile identically, but they don't. Despite the documentation saying it's a binary operator, it's implemented as a n-ary operator. The parens causes another instance of the operator to be created (effectively making it a binary operator in your examples).
2. When it's the last expression of a sub, the context is only known at run-time, which I called "indeterminate". This makes no difference except for the the list/comma operator in scalar context. The run-time context is propagated to every operand, so you get *s,s,s* if it's only know at run-time, despite getting *v,v,s* if the context is known at compile-time.

   As you can see above, this doesn't affect the answer. `E, F, G`, `( E, F ), G` and `E, ( F, G )` are equivalent whether the context is known at compile-time or not.